# Email error message using crashmail with supervisor

Tags: ubuntu, supervisord

I have a server with supervisor running an eventlistener, on the event when the process crashes, I managed to get crashmail to send an email to me. But the email content only states "Process adnode04 in group adnode04 exited unexpectedly (pid 1255) from state RUNNING".

I want crashmail to be able to take content from the last 10-20 lines of the log file and email me the contents. Is it able to do that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Absolutely, but you will have to fork [crashmail](https://github.com/Supervisor/superlance/blob/master/superlance/crashmail.py) yourself.

The message is around [line 112](https://github.com/Supervisor/superlance/blob/master/superlance/crashmail.py#L112). You can use the XML-RPC API to call [`tailProcessStderrLog`](http://supervisord.org/api.html#process-logging).

So what you'd basically do is add something like:

```
rpc = childutils.getRPCInterface( os.environ )
log = rpc.supervisor.tailProcessStderrLog( %(groupname):'%(processname)' % pheaders, 16000 )
msg += '\nLog:\n%s' % log['bytes']
```

The above is a simple proof-of-concept, untested and very probably contains a mistake. Let me know how it goes.